# Finding nearest point with lower-bound... but data is not sorted

Tags: c++, vector, std

I have a vector storing the distance to certain reference point along a line. So, I want for example the index where distance is 700 meters or the nearest value to that distance.

I have asumed the vector is sorted, and used lower_bound with success.

The problem is that in real life, errors happen, so I can not assure I'm going to have always a sorted vector, because when storaging data the user may not have followed the line for example.

How can I find the nearest value then, if data is not sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy your `vector` into an stl `set` and then use the same logic as you have done for vector for finding the element.

Comment: A sorted vector is almost always better than a set.

Comment: So, I would create a set with the pairs (vector index, distance), apply lower_bound and recover the desired index? Wouldn't that be more complex than just iterating all the vector elements into a loop?

Comment: @RomanRdgz: A `std::set` does not take pairs, it just takes an element which itself acts as an key.You misunderstand it with `std::map` which key-value pair.Also, a sorted `std::vector` is almost always going to be faster than copying all elements to an `std::set`, clearly you should use the former not the later.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot, because `std::vector` is a sequence container. You will have to **[sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)** the data using a sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::min_element` in its three-argument form. Pass a comparator that returns `true` if the first argument is closer to your target distance (700m) than the second argument. Then the result returned from `min_element` will be the closest point to the target.

Of course this is asymptotically slower than `lower_bound`, but it's asymptotically faster than the worst case of sorting the vector. If you can sort the vector once and then rely on it to stay sorted while you search for the closest point at multiple different distances, you should probably use `std::sort` and `std::lower_bound`. If finding the closest point is a one-off operation, it might well be better to do it the "slow" way with `min_element`.